# Unable to clear input react js

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React JS, I am handling a form to create new documents, there is an option that allows the user to 'clear' the input, I have gone thru other posts, however they have not helped me.

**Issue**
When I try to clear my input form, I set the state to an empty string, but that is not helping. Any help will be appreciated thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'muicss/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import { UserIsAuthenticated } from 'config.routes/UserIsAuthenticated';

import styles from './styles.scss';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      domain: '',
    };

    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
    this.clearInput = this.clearInput.bind(this);
  }

  inputChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  clearInput(){
    this.setState({domain: ''})

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.dashboardContainer}>
        <div className={styles.dashboardBody}>
          <h1>Let's Get Started</h1>
          <h5>Begin by entering a domain</h5>
          <Input
            className={styles.domainInput}
            label="Domain Name"
            type="text"
            name="domain"
            floatingLabel="true"
            onChange={this.inputChange}
            required
          />
          <Button
            variant="raised"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.onGo}
            disabled={this.state.domain.length === 0}
          >
            <Link to="/reports" style={{ color: '#fff', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
              Create Matrix {/* Todo: Replace the link */}
            </Link>
          </Button>

          <h5 onClick={this.clearInput}><Link>Reset</Link> input</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is currently uncontrolled. You are not setting the `value` of your input to your state.

```
<Input
    className={styles.domainInput}
    label="Domain Name"
    type="text"
    name="domain"
    floatingLabel="true"
    onChange={this.inputChange}
    value={this.state.domain} // <-- add this to your code
    required
  />
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Also, don't forget to spread in the rest of your state on your setState updates once you have more than one input!

Answer (score 2):

you should bind the input to the state.

Add this attribute to the input:

```
value={this.state.domain}
```